# How to emit shap value forceplot to an iframe in html?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, flask-socketio

The code below successfully displays a shap value force plot using an html front-end, by passing the variable through render_template.

The code below uses python flask backend, and javascript/html front-end.

**Python code**

```
from flask import *

import shap
from shap.plots._force_matplotlib import draw_additive_plot

#from model import give_shap_plot
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def displayshap():

   # explainer, shap_values = give_shap_plot()
    X, y = shap.datasets.diabetes()
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    
    lin_regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    lin_regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(lin_regr.predict, X_train)
    shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test.iloc[0, :])
    
    def _force_plot_html(explainer, shap_values, ind):
        force_plot = shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values, matplotlib=False) 
        shap_html = f"<head>{shap.getjs()}</head><body>{force_plot.html()}</body>"
        return shap_html

    shap_plots = {}

    for i in range(10):
        ind = i
        shap_plots[i] = _force_plot_html(explainer, shap_values, ind)
    return render_template('displayshap.html', shap_plots = shap_plots)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Html script**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SHAP HTML in Flask</title>
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />

  <style media="screen">
    html {
      --bck-color: #FFF;
      --ft-color: #000;
      --link-color: blue;
      --drop-color: #f1f8e9;
    }
    html.dark {
      --bck-color: #000;
      --ft-color: #FFF;
      --link-color: #DDD;
      --drop-color: #768763;
    }
    body {
      font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter","Lucida Console",Monaco,"Bitstream Vera Sans Mono",monospace;
      background: var(--bck-color);
      color: var(--ft-color);
      text-align: center;
    }
    iframe{
      width: 2000px;
      height: 200px;
      border: none;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <span id="toggle-switch" title="Toggle Dark Theme">
      <i class="fas fa-moon" id="toggle-switch"></i>
    </span>
  {% for i in shap_plots: %}
    <div><iframe srcdoc="{{shap_plots[i]}}" ></iframe></div>
  {% endfor %}
  </body>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='darkmode.js') }} "></script>
</html>
```

[image: forceplot]
The code runs on an anaconda environment, which is setup as follows:

```
pip install pyodbc
pip install sqlalchemy
pip install openpyxl
pip install pymssql==2.1.4 
pip install lightgbm
pip install pandas
pip install flask==1.1.1
pip install sqlalchemy
pip install flask-pymongo==2.3.0
pip install simplejson
pip install pyarrow
pip install imblearn
pip install dnspython==2.0.0
pip install pymongo[srv]
pip install flask-wtf
pip install shap
pip install matplotlib==2.2.2
pip install  Flask-Executor==0.9.4
pip install plotly
pip install Flask-SocketIO==4.3.1
pip install python-engineio==3.13.2
pip install python-socketio==4.6.0
```

I have edited and adjusted the code to emit using the shap value force plot to the html script.
Snippet code for emitting:

```
shap_plots = {}
ind = 0
shap_plots[0] = _force_plot_html(explainer, shap_values, ind)
socketio.emit('response_force_plt',shap_plots, broadcast=True)
```

Snippet html code which displays Hello world!. This code verifies that the iframe correctly updates after the emit event:

```
  <iframe id="forceplt" ></iframe>
   <script> 
            socket.on('response_force_plt', function(obj) {
                 
                 var frame = document.getElementById("forceplt")
                 frame.srcdoc = "<p>Hello world!</p>"
            });
     
   </script>
```

[image: hello world]

Snippet of html code to display force plot:

```
  <iframe id="forceplt" ></iframe>
   <script> 
            socket.on('response_force_plt', function(obj) {
                 
                 var frame = document.getElementById("forceplt")
                 frame.srcdoc = "{{obj[0]}}"
            });
     
   </script>
```

`frame.srcdoc = "{{obj[0]}}"` simply throws an undefined error for obj and the page does not display.

```
frame.srcdoc = "{{obj[0]}}"
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\lgbm\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 455, in getitem
    return obj[argument]
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'obj' is undefined
```

I have tried different scenarios by placing it in a div and updating innerhtml to add an iframe, however I have not successfully displayed the forceplot.

I noticed that the page displays if I change the following:
python

```
shap_plots = {}
ind = 0
shap_plots[0] = _force_plot_html(explainer, shap_values, ind)
#print(shap_plots[0])
socketio.emit('response_force_plt',shap_plots[0], broadcast=True) 
print("-----Emitted Force Plot 0-----")
```

html

```
    socket.on('response_force_plt', function(obj) {
         var frame = document.getElementById("forceplt")
         console.log("{{obj}}");
         frame.srcdoc =  "{{obj}}";
    });
```

In the console, obj is invisible:
[image: console]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Snippet of python code:

```
shap_plots = {}
ind = 0
shap_plots[0] = _force_plot_html(explainer, shap_values, ind)
#print(shap_plots[0])
socketio.emit('response_force_plt',shap_plots[0], broadcast=True) 
print("-----Emitted Force Plot 0-----")
```

Snippet of html code:

```
    socket.on('response_force_plt', function(obj) {
         var frame = document.getElementById("forceplt")
         console.log(obj);
         frame.srcdoc =  obj;
    });
```

Javascript did not recognise `{{ ... }}` which I used in django when passing the value through render_template.

[image: iframe]